# Can I use my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) with 4k (3840x2160) LG 40" ub800t TV @ 60Hz refresh rate?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, hdmi, resolution

As the TV only has HDMI 2.0 ports, I am considering to buy a thunderbolt to HDMI 2.0 adapter. but I want to know that whether this combination will give me the 60Hz refresh rate at 4k resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, while the LG 40UB800T TV claims that it can run at up to 100Hz as a TV. It does so through internal interpolation which adds latency and is unsuitable as a computer display.

When you run this LG TV as a computer monitor you will only be able to get 30Hz out of it at full UHD (3840x2160) resolution across an HDMI cable. To drive the LG display at UHD@60Hz you need HDMI2.0 with HDCP2.2 support.

Apple does NOT support the HDMI2.0 or HDCP2.2 standard at this time. As of late 2015 [the HDMI connector from ANY Mac will only drive a UHD display at 30Hz max according to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856?#hdmi). To drive a UHD or true 4K (4096x2400) displays at 60Hz (with full color resolution) you MUST use DisplayPort with a monitor that supports 60Hz.