# MacBook Pro Retina 15 connecting a 4k monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

Just got a new MacBook Pro 15 Retina (mid 15). I have an Acer 4k-monitor which I'm looking to connect to the MacBook but I can't figure out how. The Apple website and FAQ's weren't helpful.

I want the monitor to run 60hz, so I figured out I must use the Thunderbolt/Mini-DP connection. Since only HDMI 2.0 supports 60hz-4k (and I couldn't find out which one the MBP has).

Can I buy a Mini-DP to Mini-DP cable or is it going to work with Apple's Thunderbolt-Thunderbolt cables?

Answer (score 2):

An Apple store employee told me they no longer sell Mini-DP to Mini-DP cables because Thunderbolt cables can serve the same purpose, but [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224050/thunderbolt-vs-displayport/224087#224087) suggests she might have been lying.

I've seen a firmware revision reported for a Thunderbolt cable, which fits with the claim that a Thunderbolt cable includes a chip.

I've had good luck with DisplayPort to Mini-DP cables. If your monitor has a full size DisplayPort connector, connecting a cable to that might be your best bet. Cables for that purpose are easy to find on Amazon.

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222763/149185) confirms my experience, that a Mac HDMI port can't do UHD at 60 Hz.